# Identify rows subsequent to other rows based on criteria?

Tags: sql, db2

I am fairly new to DB2 and SQL. There exists a table of customers and their visits. I need to write a query to find visits by the same customer subsequent and within 24hr to a visit when Sale = 'Y'.

Based on this example data:

| CustomerId | VisitID | Sale | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y | 2021-04-23 20:16:00.000000 |
| 2 | 2 | N | 2021-04-24 20:16:00.000000 |
| 1 | 3 | N | 2021-04-23 21:16:00.000000 |
| 2 | 4 | Y | 2021-04-25 20:16:00.000000 |
| 3 | 5 | Y | 2021-04-23 20:16:00.000000 |
| 2 | 6 | N | 2021-04-25 24:16:00.000000 |
| 3 | 7 | N | 2021-5-23 20:16:00.000000 |

The query results should return:

| VisitID |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 6 |

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You may uncomment the commented out block to run this statement as is.

```
/*
WITH MYTAB (CustomerId, VisitID, Sale, DateTime) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (1, 3, 'N', '2021-04-23 21:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (2, 2, 'N', '2021-04-24 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (2, 4, 'Y', '2021-04-25 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (2, 6, 'N', '2021-04-25 23:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (3, 5, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
, (3, 7, 'N', '2021-05-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
)
*/
SELECT VisitID
FROM MYTAB A
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM MYTAB B
WHERE B.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
AND B.Sale = 'Y'
AND B.VisitID <> A.VisitID
AND A.DateTime BETWEEN B.DateTime AND B.DateTime + 24 HOUR
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask my questions in this format in the future!